# How to QUERY a SPLIT csv and find the value that matches criteria in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to `SPLIT("1,4,10,17",",")` and then use `QUERY` to find the lowest number that is higher or equal to a number of my choice.

So for example, if my choice is 5, it will return 4 or if my choice was 15 then the result would be 10.

What would be the right query string?
`QUERY(SPLIT("1,4,10,17",","),"<what do I write here?>"`

Edit: I need this to work in an ARRAYFORMULA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
=lambda(z,xlookup(C1,z,z,,-1))(split(A1,","))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this does work but I should've mentioned in my question that I need it to work in an `ARRAYFORMULA` so that's why I needed query as (unless I'm doing it wrong) it seems that xlookup doesn't play well in arrayformulas

Comment: `xlookup` works just fine with `arrayformula()`

Comment: When I changed to `xlookup(C1:C,z,z,,-1)` when inside an `arrayformula` I get "XLOOKUP range must be a single row or a single column."

Comment: it would help if you could share a sample sheet with demo data maybe and desired output so that it gives a clear picture of what is needed.

Comment: [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16aaRdy4STvX8G54vE34juvlfZx-2O4L9P6QPWMTXg9E/edit#gid=0)

Comment: the `lookup_range` in your scenario is not single row or column (https://i.imgur.com/ma08nI4.png); so the error. you may try this formula instead: `=map(A2:A,B2:B,lambda(a,b,if(a="",,xlookup(b,split(a,","),split(a,","),,-1))))`